# Regular expression with more than one ~ (not) part

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I'm using the following regular expression:

```
~(sizeof)\(<int|long>\)
```

to match:

```
blah blah (int)variable blah blah
blah blah (long)variable blah blah
```

but not:

```
blah blah sizeof(int) blah blah
```

That all works. Now, I want to further **not** match:

```
HMODULE (WINAPI *fnPtr)(int) = NULL;
```

so I tried:

```
~(sizeof|fnPtr\))\(<int|long>\)
```

but it still matches the `fnPtr` line. How should I alter the regular expression to **not** match that line?

(I'm using the regular expression search in Visual Studio 2005.)

(I've greatly simplified the regular expression in as much as the `int|long` part is really `int|long|...` where `...` is about 40 other types.)

Edit:

Nevermind, I've solved it. You need to do:

```
~(sizeof|(fnPtr.))\(<int|long>\)
```

which is replace the `fnPtr\)` with `(fnPtr.)`, so that the `.` matches the bracket, and so that the `.` is associated with `fnPtr`.

Comment: VS has a different flavor of regex patterns. I would advise to do the replace in some other editor (e.g. Notepad++) and then bring the results in VS. Not that it can't be done in VS, but you need to learn a different syntax which I prefer not to.

Comment: I could try it in UltraEdit - I think that uses Perl regular expressions - but I'd obviously prefer not to have to manage 100s of files using two separate programs where one (should) work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `[\w\s]+ \((int|long)\)[\w ]+`

Here's a demo: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=d18853f4-a737-4509-8c7b-babd0e9272d2

**Note:** Read my comment to your post. This is standard regex, not VS regex. You can adopt it accordingly.

Comment: I can't use the site you have linked to because it requires Microsoft Silverlight. Could you explain what your expression does so that I can try to adapt it to VS2005?

Comment: As far as I can tell from the net, [\w\s]+ matches one or more words and spaces. How does this *not* match the fnPtr line?

Comment: Instead of not matching, I use positive matching - I match only `[\w\s]+` followed by `(int)` or `(long)`. I had a feeling there is more than what meets the eye and your edit confirms that.